# Error in adding an avd

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to add an avd, but the ok button is disabled:

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: what ideas could you eliminate yet?

Answer (score 1):

No system images installed for this target.

Run the SDK manager and install the missing packages.